# Why does mergesort not work if I pass slow.next instead of mid?

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion, data-structures, mergesort

In this code for mergesort, why can you pass mid but not slow.next directly in the recursive call to sortList? in line number 13, How is passing mid = slow.next different than directly passing slow.next?

```
class Solution:
    def sortList(self, head: ListNode) -> ListNode:
        if not head or not head.next:
            return head
        fast = head.next
        slow = head
        while fast and fast.next:
            fast = fast.next.next
            slow = slow.next
        mid = slow.next
        slow.next = None
        l = self.sortList(head)
        r = self.sortList(slow.next)##instead pass mid here, and it works.
        return self.merge(l,r)
    
    def merge(self, l, r):
        if not l or not r:
            return l or r
        if l.val > r.val:
            l, r = r, l
        # get the return node "head"
        head = pre = l
        l = l.next
        while l and r:
            if l.val < r.val:
                l = l.next
            else:
                nxt = pre.next
                pre.next = r
                tmp = r.next
                r.next = nxt
                r = tmp
            pre = pre.next
        # l and r at least one is None
        pre.next = l or r
        return head
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first assigned `slow.next` to `mid`, so `mid` now holds the start of the second part of your list. Then you assigned `None` to `slow.next`, so if you now call `self.sortList(slow.next)`, the second part of the list would not be sorted.

If you call `self.sortList(mid)`, then because `mid` is the pointer to the second part of the list, the mergesort works.

Comment: It would be great if people collapse this.